# Matlab Randi lab Vectors

Tags: matlab, vector

Im doing a lab using matlab and have hit a bit of a snag. The prompt is:

a. Generate a vector to manipulate in the following exercises by using a random
number generator to create "pull-ups" counts for 50 people. The counts should be
from 1 to 10. Use this vector of counts for the next two problems.

b. How many people did more than 5 pull-ups? Do your results make sense for a
uniformly distributed random number generator?

c. Generate another vector for "pull-ups" counts 50 athletes, so this time use the
range from 11 to 20. Append this new vector to the previous vector (now you have
100 "pull-ups" counts).

d. Find the average number of "pull-ups" for the 100 total people. Do your results
make sense?

e. Use the 100 person vector in c and create a new vector that contains only the
counts from the odd-numbered índices (not the odd value counts, instead the
counts for every other person starting with person 1).
f. Use the 100 person vector in c and make a new vector of the "even-valued
counts".

Now, I can do parts a. and b. with no problem, but i do not have an idea on how to do part c. Ive been trying to do this

x=randi(20,11,50)

now i know that i get 110 values that range from 1 to 20 doing what i put above. But im trying to get 50 values from 11 to 20 and add those values to the vector in part a so that i have 100 values, with 50 ranging from 1-10  and the other 50 ranging from 11-20. Any idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: This question is directly addressed by the documentation. Type `help randi` or `doc rand` in your Command Window.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an *array* as the first input to `randi` to specify the lower and upper limits of the random integers. If you specify just a scalar, then values between `1` and your provided values will be returned. The second and third inputs are the *size* of the output so we want the output to be `50 x 1`

```
x = randi([11 20], 50, 1)
```